# why outliers are heavily punished if the error is squared

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, gradient-descent, loss-functions

It is well known that outliers are heavily punished if  the error is squared.
Someone please explain with a simple example how  this is the case? Please compare this with absolute error.

I am going through [this document](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/vip/teach/MLcourse/4_boosting/lecture_notes/boosting/boosting.pdf).

In page 10, section 4.3.2 *Regression with Other Loss Functions*, it is mentioned that outliers are heavily punished because the error is squared.

I need further clarification on this.

Comment: Why don't you plot the functions $f(x) = x^2$ and $f(x)  = |x|$ and compare them?

Comment: @JohnK, Yes I plot these functions.But how can I conclude these from the plot.My x axis is the actual error and y axis is the loss function.But who is punished here and how?Please elaborate.

Comment: @Sve   I am not asking for mathematics and want to know the intuition behind it.

Comment: What do you mean by "outliers are heavily punished"?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: It's odd wording to my mind: if there is punishment, it's of the researcher, not the outlier. But the document gives an example and then an explanation: "The consequence is that the algorithm pays too much attention to outliers. It tries hard to incorporate outliers into the model. Doing so may degrade the overall performance."

Comment: imagine you have 10 residuals with values +/-1  and 1 residual of 10. then using the absolute they are roughly matched, whereas using squared error, the residual 10 has 10 times greater effect (ie you need 100 small residuals to have the same impact as 1 residual of size 10)

Answer (score 1):

"Punished" makes sense in the context of the document you cited, since it is talking about loss functions.  A single outlier, squared, can add a lot to the loss function (thus making the model look worse).  The table on the same page in the document compares square loss to absolute loss and Huber loss and shows that the latter two are more resistant to outliers.

Comment: @Pramod Kishore If you feel that the answer is acceptable, you may accept it.